# What is the correct pronunciation of "tuple"?

Tags: pronunciation

I found someone who reads it as /t^pl/, who reads it as /tupl/, and who reads it as /tju:pl/.

What's the correct pronunciation of *tuple*?

Comment: tjuːp(ə)l according to my Oxford version.

Comment: There's more than one valid pronunciation.

Comment: I've never heard tjuːp(ə)l (despite doing a PhD in logic).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I pronounce it such that it rhymes with the word "couple". I work with Software Developers for a range of different countries and we all pronounce the word this way.

Comment: All the mathematicians and logicians I worked with pronounced it with the "up" rather than "coup" sound. So that's interesting.

Answer (score 1):

It should be pronounced the same as the last two syllables of [quintuple](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/quintuple?q=quintuple) (and *quadruple, sextuple, septuple*), since this is the etymological origin of the word. Unfortunately, not everybody pronounces *quintuple* the same way, and the dictionaries give various pronunciations.

Comment: Actually, I always hear "quadruple" (to increase by 4x) pronounced as the "u" in "super", but "quintuple" ("sextuple", etc) pronounced as in supple. Perhaps it's a noun/verb thing in the US.